# Можно ли так составить SQL-запрос?

Tags: запрос, php, sql, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT table_name FROM orders WHERE id_client=3 and id_agent=1) WHERE id_product=$idp
```

Там выбирает название таблицы, и из нее выводит информацию

В orders есть список таблиц, вот я их и подставляю. и с каждой таблицы беру данные.

Comment: возможно так?

SELECT * FROM (SELECT table_name, id_product FROM orders WHERE id_client=3 and id_agent=1) WHERE id_product=$idp

Comment: Это неправильно логически. Ваш запрос будет идентичен с `"SELECT table_name FROM orders WHERE id_client=3 and id_agent=1 and id_product=" .$idp`. Вам нужно разложить этот запрос на два. В oracle есть dynamic sql для такого, в mysql насколько я знаю нет

Comment: Если так уж сильно хочется пользоваться неудобоваримой архитектурой.

```
$table = $db->queryScalar('SELECT table_name FROM orders WHERE id_client=3 and id_agent=1');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE id_product = '.$idp;
$data = $db->queryAll($query);
```

На месте мускуля я бы тоже отказался работать хотя бы по той причине, что может вернуться сто таблиц.

Comment: реквестирую тэг "мозг-на-костылях".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На выходе из подзапроса возвращается один столбец - table_name.
Поэтому условие

```
WHERE id_product=$idp
```

просто приведет к ошибке типа "неизвестный столбец id_product".

Comment: @msi, автор хочет запросом вытянуть таблицу и тут же пихнуть еее в from следующего запроса

Comment: SELECT * FROM (                     
SELECT table_name, id_product FROM orders WHERE id_client =10 AND id_agent =2
) AS tb

Возвращает от 0 - 100 таблиц, и нужно по очереди выбрать все поля из тех таблиц(поля одинаковые) но мне возвращает только имена таблиц, а 2й запрос на то что бы из этих имен выбрать все поля уже не работает

Comment: @Юра Сучко, лол? Как в один from можно запихнуть сотню таблиц?

Comment: Это максимум 100, а так 1-10, и по очереди брать с них информацию, учитывая то что у них структура идентична, только записи

Comment: @Юра Сучко, хорошо, *больше одной*? Чтобы *внезапно* по одним и тем же ключам выбиралось из всех таблиц разом.

Comment: Таблицы это - "категории товаров". Да, перебор списка таблиц по очереди.

Comment: @Юра Сучко, ну вот я спрашиваю, каким магическим образом приведенный запрос это может сделать.

Comment: Это была моя идея что такое можно реализовать в SQL, если нет. значит я ошибся. Вопрос то я задал про возможность создания такого запроса

Comment: Создайте курсор на основе подзапроса. Обойдите его в цикле, и динамически выполняйте запрос для каждой таблицы.